# Run Ansible via Shell Command on Remote GCP Servers

Tags: ansible

I have 3 Linux servers A, B and C. A is where all the developers use, B is a Ansible server that has a playbook, C is the target server that I need to run some tasks.

This is the frame of the playbook - play.yml:

```
---
- name: get inst info
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - debug: msg="Before going to {{ target_instance }}"

- hosts: "{{ target_instance }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: root

  tasks:

  - debug: msg="In {{ target_instance }}"
```

On A, I will issue the command:

```
user_a@A~$ ssh B "cd <ansible_playbook_dir>; ansible-playbook play.yml -e \"target_instance=wolf\""
```

and the output:

```
PLAY [get inst info] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Involve general variables] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:08:00 +0000 (0:00:00.023)       0:00:00.023 ***** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Involve prodcopy variables] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:08:00 +0000 (0:00:00.021)       0:00:00.045 ***** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:08:01 +0000 (0:00:00.019)       0:00:00.065 ***** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Before going to wolf"
}

PLAY [wolf] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:08:01 +0000 (0:00:00.077)       0:00:00.143 ***** 
ok: [wolf]

TASK [debug] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:08:02 +0000 (0:00:01.877)       0:00:02.021 ***** 
ok: [wolf] => {
    "msg": "In wolf"
}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
wolf                       : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Thursday 04 November 2021  23:08:02 +0000 (0:00:00.031)       0:00:02.052 ***** 
===============================================================================
```

But if I run the same command as a user that has passphrase with his ssh key,

```
user_b@A~$ ssh B "cd <ansible_playbook_dir; ansible-playbook play.yml -e \"target_instance=wolf\""
```

I got the ssh error:

```
PLAY [get inst info] ***********************************************************

TASK [Involve general variables] ***********************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:00:42 +0000 (0:00:00.025)       0:00:00.025 ***** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Involve prodcopy variables] **********************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:00:42 +0000 (0:00:00.039)       0:00:00.065 ***** 
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:00:42 +0000 (0:00:00.037)       0:00:00.103 ***** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Before going to wolf"
}

PLAY [wolf] ****************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
Thursday 04 November 2021  23:00:42 +0000 (0:00:00.048)       0:00:00.151 ***** 
fatal: [wolf]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: user_b@wolf: Permission denied (publickey).", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
wolf                       : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Thursday 04 November 2021  23:00:42 +0000 (0:00:00.066)       0:00:00.218 ***** 
===============================================================================
```

I have keychain setup on A and B for user_b.

Is there anyway I can make this working for users who has passphrase for their ssh keys?

Thanks!

Comment: Contains the frame of your playbook still the same content as in SO [Run Ansible vai shell command on remote GCP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69818249/)? Or have you removed the part of "_invoking ssh manually from within a shell_" since it was mentioned as an anti pattern?

Comment: Is your question more related to [How to run `ansible-playbook` with a passphrase protected ssh key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277495/). You may also take note of [Setting up SSH keys](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/connection_details.html#setting-up-ssh-keys).